# Accessing ListBox DisplayMemberPath data value in SelectedItem template

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I am attempting to create a generic ListBox control to customize edit in place as well as other features.

In the example below, I want to bind the "Text" property of the ListBox "selected item" to the data value of the DisplayMemberPath in the viewed structure. Such XAML binding expression would replace the question marks in the code (Text="{Binding ????????????????").

Using a ContentPresenter instead of binding the text works for display purposes, but I have not been able to bind to the Text component used on the presenter. An alternative to finding the binding expression is to be able to get the Text content from the ContentPresenter.

I can think of a number of ways to accomplish this through code behind, but I am looking for a XAML solution if such thing exists.

I appreciate any ideas. I am almost sure there is a trivial answer to this, but after spending a couple days on it, I admit a nudge in the right direction would greatly help me.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="NobelLaureatesInPhysics"
                     XPath="/NobelLaureatesInPhysics">
        <x:XData>
            <NobelLaureatesInPhysics xmlns="">
                <NobelLaureate>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <Name>Wilhelm Röntgen</Name>
                    <AwardDate>12/10/1901</AwardDate>
                </NobelLaureate>
                <NobelLaureate>
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <Name>Hendrik Lorentz</Name>
                    <AwardDate>12/10/1902</AwardDate>
                </NobelLaureate>
                <NobelLaureate>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <Name>Pieter Zeeman</Name>
                    <AwardDate>12/10/1902</AwardDate>
                </NobelLaureate>
            </NobelLaureatesInPhysics>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate"
                     TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black">
             <ContentPresenter />
        </TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedItemTemplate"
                     TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <TextBox Background="Black"
                 Foreground="White"
                 Text="{Binding ????????????????"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
           x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TestListBoxStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle"
                Value="{DynamicResource ContainerStyle}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Style="{DynamicResource TestListBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NobelLaureatesInPhysics}, XPath=NobelLaureate}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{Binding Path=DisplayMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, Type={x:Type ListBox}}
```

That should work

Comment: This will get you the ListBox.DisplayMemberPath property, e.g. "Name".  I believe the poster wants to get the value of that property on the item at hand, e.g. "Hendrik Lorentz".

Comment: Oh silly me Oo sorry.
They way I usually go about doing this is a MemberPathConverter. A MultiValueConverter that takes the listboxitem's value and the binding listed above. Then do your reflection in the converter to find the required Property.

Comment: As noted, the intention is to get the value pointed by the DisplayMemberPath. e.g. If a "nested" binding was allowed, I would actually do something like: Binding Path={Binding Path=DisplayMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, Type={x:Type ListBox}}}. Also, converter or other code behind solutions are available, but I was wondering if either Binding or Property syntax would offer a more elegant/maintenable declarative solution.